# Internal Server Error returning from C# WebMethod to JavaScript AJAX call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I can't get the AJAX call to get the return from the C# WebMethod. It always returns the AJAX error "Internal Server Error".

A button calls JS function:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="Create();">foo</button>
```

The JS function:

```
function Create() {
var data = {
    value1: 'string 1',
    value2: 'string 2',
    value3: 'string 3'
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'default.aspx/Create',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ formData: data }),
    async: true,
    success: function (msg, status) {
        alert("success " + msg.d);
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        alert("failure " + msg.d);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
return false;
}
```

And the C# WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Create(string data)
{
    return "webmethod string";
}
```

Can anyone point me where is the mistake?

Comment: You need to change : JSON.stringify({ formData: data }) to : JSON.stringify({ data: data }) since your server side formal parameter is data not formData, or simply data:data. This would result in a 404 error, however. A 500 means you have a configuration issue of a server side error caused the request from returning a valid response.

Comment: You're correct about that. But also "data: data" isn't working.

Comment: So what is in the error log on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string but the success method is expecting json. 
Ajax doc here:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Datatype property:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback)

Change datatype to "text"

Also chnage your paramater from "formData" to "data"

code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'default.aspx/Create',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success " + data);
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        alert("failure " + msg.d);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

3:d edit here:
you are sending an object in you ajax call but your paramater on server side is a string. change it to a class instance with the same name properties as the object that you are sending

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how exactly i get the return value from the C# WebMethod? The "data" we get is a complete document.

Comment: Check the bottom of my answer please. you are sending in an object with 3 string properties but your server method is accepting a string

Comment: I did all that now. Thanks. It's now accepting a class instance with the same name properties as the object that i am sending. However, the success alert still shows a whole html document, not my return value (MyNewInstanceYouSuggested.value1)

Comment: You are not returning "myinstance.value1"
you are returning a string 'return "webmethod string";'

Comment: check here:http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

NOTE if you want to retrurn a json then you must change you datatype property from "text" to "json"

Comment: i did all your recommendations, it's now accepting a class instance and returning value1 (the same name as the JS object property). But still, the alert shows a whole document. I'll look into your link.

Comment: could you please send a screenshot of what your data object in the success method contains? if you have firebug just check what you get back and upload a screenshot please. i don't understand how you can be getting a document? EDIT: please edit the question with you updated code

Comment: shouldn't i paste a new question instead of editing this one? There's a lot of changes and it's pratically a whole new subject with a lot of new code, as i have no "internal server error" anymore. What are the guidelines for this? I guess a new, concise question with screenshot would be better.

Comment: you should  not ask several question related to the first one. That will be considered as "spam". Update this question in order for me or some1 else to help you reach a soloution